# Trigger error before delete on custom object

Tags: trigger, custom-object, record, delete

I have a `custom object` in `salesforce` called : `File_Uploaded__c` with many fields such as `Name, Size, DeletionDate__c` and i declared a `trigger` to set the deletion date when a record is deleted, here's my `trigger` code:

```
trigger setDeletionDate on File_Uploaded__c (before delete) {
    for (File_Uploaded__c f: Trigger.old) {
       f.DeletionDate__c = date.Today();
    }
}
```

But when i try to delete a record of my custom object i get this error:

```
There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Apex trigger setDeletionDate caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: setDeletionDate: execution of BeforeDelete caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Trigger.setDeletionDate: line 3, column 1".
```

**EDIT 1:**

I changed `Trigger.old` to `Trigger.new` I'm getting a new error:

```
 There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Apex trigger setDeletionDate caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: setDeletionDate: execution of BeforeDelete caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.setDeletionDate: line 2, column 1".
```

Comment: You can't modify records in the trigger set during a before delete trigger - the record will be deleted and hence updating it doesn't make sense since you won't be seeing it again in a query

Comment: so how can i update `DeletionDate__c` field when i delete my object ?

Comment: i'm not 100% sure but systemModstamp may have the deleted date. Others on SFSE can confirm this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching and trying many solutions, i finally find one, i let the code here if any one has the same problem:

```
trigger setDeletionDate on File_Uploaded__c (before delete) {
Set<Id> fileIds = Trigger.oldMap.keyset();
list<File_Uploaded__c> files = [SELECT Id, DeletionDate__c FROM File_Uploaded__c WHERE Id IN :fileIds];  
for (File_Uploaded__c f: files) {
       f.DeletionDate__c = system.now();
       update f;
 } 
}
```